# Angular ng build throws error write EPIPE

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I tried to build an angular app with `ng build` but I got this error:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:164:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:155:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:795:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:807:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Socket.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Object.writeToStdin (/home/[user]/example/node_modules/esbuild-wasm/lib/main.js:1864:19)
    at sendRequest (/home/[user]/example/node_modules/esbuild-wasm/lib/main.js:637:14)
    at start (/home/[user]/example/node_modules/esbuild-wasm/lib/main.js:1274:9)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

I have checked many questions like this but didn't solve my problem. this error is a little different from others.

Angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.2
Node: 16.13.2
Package Manager: npm 
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1301.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.1.2
@angular-devkit/core            13.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.2
@angular/cli                    13.2.2
@schematics/angular             13.2.2
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.5.4
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrading `Angular` and `Node` versions did the trick.

```
Angular CLI 13.2.2 -> 12.2.16
Node 16.13.2 -> 14.19.0
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who comes across this: I encountered an error like this in a docker build (ng 12, node 16). My problem turned out to be that I was inadvertently shipping node_modules in my build context, presumably containing some cruft from my mac box that interferes with a build in linux. Adding node_modules to .dockerignore fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade node 14.19.0 will works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).